# rails ActiveRecord can you merge scopes that have joins within them?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I am wanting to join a single table to another table with a specific scope.

What I had tried to do does not work, but a version using sub-select works correctly.

`MyModel` `belongs_to` a `User` class (which `has_one` `MyModel`) and the user class has a scope that involves joins to other tables.

What I am trying to do is:

```
# doesn't work, gives user that is not inside the merged scope
MyModel.joins(:user).merge(User.has_accounts)
```

This generates the following SQL which I think should do what I want:

```
SELECT DISTINCT "my_model".* FROM
"my_model" INNER JOIN "users" ON "users"."id" = 
"my_model"."user_id" LEFT OUTER JOIN "logins" ON 
"logins"."user_id" = "users"."id" LEFT OUTER JOIN "logins" 
"logins_users_join" ON "logins_users_join"."user_id" = "users"."id" 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "accounts" ON "accounts"."login_id" = 
"logins_users_join"."id"
```

The user scope "`has_accounts`" has some joins inside it:

```
scope :has_accounts, -> { joins(:logins).joins(:accounts).distinct }
```

I am able to write write the query correctly using a sub-select like so:

```
# works does not give my_model that has a user associated that is not in the scope
MyModel.where(user_id: User.has_accounts.select(:id))
```

The relevant parts of the model are as follows:

```
class MyModel
  belongs_to :user
end

class User
  has_one :my_model
  has_many :logins
  has_many :accounts, through: :logins
  scope :has_accounts, -> { joins(:logins).joins(:accounts).distinct }
end

class Login
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :accounts
end

class Account
  belongs_to :login
end
```

what am I doing wrong with my `join` and `merge` so that it does not give the correct result?

Can anyone see what it is in the generated `SQL` that means that the users that do not have an associated account are present in the result?

Comment: would changing `has_accounts` to `scope :has_accounts, -> { joins(:logins).joins(:accounts).group('users.id')` make `MyModel.joins(:user).merge(User.has_accounts)` produce expected result?

Comment: @AndreyDeineko no, it doesn't appear to. It also changes the semantics of the existing queries that rely on the scope. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: please edit the question with the associations between user login and account ( i assume user has one account which has many logins?)

Comment: @AndreyDeineko sure, I'll add them to the question. It's actually the other way around, a user has many logins and each login can have many accounts.

Comment: you do not need both `joins` in `has_accounts` - `joins(:logins).distinct` should be enough - `.joins(:accounts)` is redundant (because of `through` association).

Comment: The scope `joins(:logins).joins(:accounts).distinct` is very ambiguous. Which columns should be used?  You should add an example of the tables and the desired result. Also please add which database you are using.

Comment: Account should `have_one :user, through: :login`.

Comment: @AndreyDeineko you mean that the `joins(:logins)` isn't necessary, right? the accounts are through the logins. Either way, it's beside the point as it doesn't help me figure out why the `merge` doesn't work.

Comment: yea, I say `joins(:logins)` makes no use for you. If removing it still does not produce the correct result for you (when using `merge`) it's strange, since it should.

Comment: @max `belongs_to` actually, which I forgot to include here in this pared down example, but the problem still stands.

Comment: @AndreyDeineko removing it still does not solve the problem. Glad that other people think it should work, it's had me very confused...

Comment: If `Account` belongs_to `user` you may have a problem since you have both a direct and indirect relation and ActiveRecord may not be keeping the foreign key up to date when you create records.

Comment: @max my wonder was about the `OUTER JOIN` that was present in the generated SQL, when I manually swap those to `INNER JOIN` the relation appears to behave as expected, but I don't understand why activerecord is generating outer joins?

Answer (score 1):

After digging into this for a while it seems that it is a bug in activerecord. It is referred to in this issue:

https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/16140

and it is implied that it is a bug due to this PR:

https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/26195

The bug causes OUTER JOINS to be generated on merging something with joins into another query, instead of INNER JOINS